# Need help in understanding flow of events when we perform update or delete statements in MS SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not able to correctly understand the flow of events when we perform an update/delete statement in sql server.As per understanding below events occur,but still in confusion.Can you please clarify this or post a detailed event log

A.)Update statement performed on a DB in full recovery mode  and committed

DB reads the page from the disk if not in memory and page data will be modified.

Same will be written in Tlog file and the log buffer hardens this to disk before the mdf file is written to disk.

Lazy writer or Tlog backup will force the MDF to write to disk under some circumstances.

But still some questions on this

B.)I am always under assumption that ,when you modify something in SQL server that will be written to log file first and when checkpoint occurs this will be moved into MDF file.

Can you help me understand which one is correct,is it A or B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately i found answer i am looking for posting here,incase if it might help some one

SQL Server 2012 : SQL Server Architecture - THE LIFE CYCLE OF A QUERY (part 3) - A Simple Update Query
Read more at http://mscerts.programming4.us/sql_server/SQL%20Server%202012%20%20%20SQL%20Server%20Architecture%20-%20THE%20LIFE%20CYCLE%20OF%20A%20QUERY%20(part%203)%20-%20A%20Simple%20Update%20Query.aspx#S7WVSwMhfbLq85TC.99